# An internal error occurred during: "Task List Indexer". For input string: "1 2"

Tags: eclipse, installation

Today I reinstalled the OS on my Macbook Pro, and then installed Eclipse with iCloud synchronization.

After I finished installing Eclipse, I started the Eclipse IDE, but was faced with this message:

> An internal error occurred during: "Task List Indexer". For input string: "1 2".

I've never seen anything like this before. When I looked up, there was a message saying that it was out of memory.

If you know the solution or cause of this problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change **mylyn task lists** folder location in *preferences* and import old task lists.

Comment: thanks. at first backup my old .taskListIndex then i restart Eclipse.app. so this problem is solved.